# Why do we have to release objects when using Quartz API?

Tags: ios, objective-c, quartz-2d

I've recently been learning how to use the Quartz API in iOS development, and have noticed a number of things that have been a little strange. For 1, why do we have to release certain objects after making them? Also, pointer variables don't have the asterisk, why is that? Like the code below:

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
```

In the above example, the variable context is a pointer. Why don't we use the asterisk? Appreciate any help/guidance. Please be as thorough as you can because I like to have insightful knowledge of the technologies I use.

Comment: I'll just comment because I don't have time for an in-depth answer right now. The short answer is that you are dealing with a C-level API (not written in or wrapped in Objective-C). `CGContextRef` is a `typedef` of a pointer to a struct (C does not have classes, but structs are a container type). Take a look at the definition of `CGContextRef` in CGContext.h and you will see the asterisk syntax used there. Automatic Reference Counting (ARC) is a compiler feature that only operates on Obj-C objects and therefore memory allocated by this and other C level APIs must be explicitly released.

Comment: @Mathew Thanks! I was also curious whether developers tend to use this more than say creating images in a software like Sketch when designing UI graphics for apps? I'm new to the UI Graphics stuff.

Comment: @Mathew If you want, just copy/paste your comment as an answer, and I'll pick it as best answer.

Comment: I am not a graphic designer, but this is my experience: any time you are going to display a static graphic in an iOS app and not manipulate it beyond basic transformations (scaling, rotating) you are better off (for efficiency reasons) using a png file. Once you get into more demanding dynamic manipulation of the graphic such as a swirling effect, it probably becomes worth doing some prototyping and profiling with Quartz to see if you can gain efficiency by using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are dealing with a C-level API (not written in or wrapped in Objective-C). `CGContextRef` is a `typedef` of a pointer to a `struct` (C does not have classes, but `structs` are a container type). Take a look at the definition of `CGContextRef` in *CGContext.h* and you will see the asterisk syntax used there.

There is one primary reason I can think of why Apple would define `CGContextRef` rather than having programmers work with pointers to `CGContext` structs directly. In Objective-C, you are always working with pointers. You never work with statically allocated Objective-C class instances -- in fact, the compiler forbids it. In C, however, this is not true. Apple would like to keep all references to `CGContext` structs as pointers so that reference counting works as expected and they can guarantee the object you are using is the same one they gave you. Side note: Reference counting itself is not a part of the C language, it is something Apple has written into structs like `CGContext` to allow programming with them to feel similar to programming with Objective-C objects. Consider the following code snippets as terse examples of what I am talking about.

In C (and you can compile this as part of an Objective-C program):

```
typedef struct {int a; int b; int refCount;} SimpleObject;

SimpleObject *obj1 = malloc(sizeof(SimpleObject));
obj1->a = 5;
obj1->b = 6;
obj1->refCount = 1;

SimpleObject *obj2 = obj1;

NSLog(@"test: (%d, %d) (%d, %d) (%d, %d)", obj1->a, obj2->a, obj1->b, obj2->b, obj1->refCount, obj2->refCount);
NSLog(@"test: %d", obj1 == obj2); //they are literally the same object (same location in memory)

SimpleObject obj3 = *obj1;

NSLog(@"test: (%d, %d) (%d, %d) (%d, %d)", obj1->a, obj3.a, obj1->b, obj3.b, obj1->refCount, obj3.refCount);
NSLog(@"test: %d", obj1 == &obj3); //they are not the same object (same location in memory)

obj1->refCount--;

NSLog(@"test: how many retains on obj1? %d  how about obj2? %d  and obj3? %d", obj1->refCount, obj2->refCount, obj3.refCount);

free(obj1);
```

Try something similar in Objective-C and the compiler throws an error pretty quickly:

```
NSObject *obj1 = [[NSObject alloc] init];

NSObject *obj2 = obj1;

NSLog(@"test: %d", obj1 == obj2); // they are literally the same object (same location in memory)

NSObject obj3 = obj1; // compiler error
```

Automatic Reference Counting (ARC) is what allows you to allocate memory in Objective-C and then not worry about releasing or deallocating it later. This is a compiler feature that only operates on Obj-C objects and therefore memory allocated by this and other C level APIs must be explicitly released.